# What's the meaning of "colour pretended"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What's the meaning of "colour pretended" in the following passage?

> ... after the first formation of the universe, all the things are brought to pass by the settled laws of nature. For though this be confidently, and not without colour pretended; yet... I look upon a law as being indeed but a notional thing, according to which an intelligent and free agent is bound to regulate his action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase *not without color* is an adverbial phrase. It is modifying *pretended*. The use of *not without color* means, in effect, *with some degree of color*.

Now for the sense of *color*. Here, I think the best fit definition is this one:
[Collins *color*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/color)
11.  **outward appearance or semblance; plausibility**

In modern usage, the word *pretend* means to believe or assert something that you think is false. In the archaic use here, I believe it means to assert something, without any hint that you think it is false. I haven't found a reference to prove this.

Now, rephrasing the passage,

> For, though this be confidently and **somewhat plausibly asserted**, yet I look upon a law as a notional thing...

(It sounds as if the passage is about whether the universe is under divine control. It allows that the idea of natural laws controlling things is plausible, while maintaining that there is something divine behind it all which freely follows those laws.)